TraceId in Spring Boot 3 is not propagated
I try to propagate the trace Id between micro service calls. It does not seem the RestTemplate propagates the traceId, even though I am using RestTemplateBuilder and have actuator and a tracing bridge in the classpath.
I am running on Spring Boot 3.3.3 and Java 17. here the pom.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>tracepropagation</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>tracepropagation</name>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-tracing-bridge-otel</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>


This is my RestTemplate config
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(AppProperties.class)
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build();
    }
}

I test with a simple request forward to the same service using the rest template:
@RestController
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class AppController {

    private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
    private final AppProperties props;

    @GetMapping(path = "/forward")
    public String forward() {
        log.info("forward endpoint entered");
        return this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + props.getPort() + "/hello", String.class);
    }

    @GetMapping(path = "/hello")
    public String hello(){
        log.info("hello endpoint entered");
        return "hello";
    }
}

I wrote a test case, which expects the same trace Id in the log from the /forward endpoint and the log in the /hello endpoint:
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
class TracepropagationApplicationTests {

    @LocalServerPort
    private int port;

    @Autowired
    private AppProperties props;

    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate restTemplate;

    @Captor
    ArgumentCaptor<ILoggingEvent> logCaptor;

    @Mock
    private Appender<ILoggingEvent> mockAppender;


    @BeforeEach
    void beforeEach(){
        final Logger root = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Logger.ROOT_LOGGER_NAME);
        when(this.mockAppender.getName()).thenReturn("MOCK");
        root.addAppender(this.mockAppender);
        root.setLevel(Level.INFO);
        doNothing().when(mockAppender).doAppend(logCaptor.capture());
    }

    @Test
    void testTraceIdPropagation() {
        props.setPort(port);
        assertThat(restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:" + port + "/forward", String.class)).isEqualTo("hello");
        String firstLogTraceId = this.getLogTraceId("forward endpoint entered");
        String secondLogTraceId = this.getLogTraceId("hello endpoint entered");
        assertThat(firstLogTraceId).isEqualTo(secondLogTraceId);
    }

    private String getLogTraceId(String logMessage) {
        var traceOptional = logCaptor.getAllValues().stream().filter(e -> e.getFormattedMessage().contains(logMessage))
                .findAny()
                .map(ILoggingEvent::getMDCPropertyMap)
                .map(m -> m.get("traceId"));
        assertThat(traceOptional).isPresent();
        return traceOptional.get();
    }
}


However, this test case fails. From what I read in the documentation, the auto configuration should work, if I use the RestTemplateBuilder autowired from Spring Boot.
It does not seem to propagate the trace Id though.
thx in advance!
Here also the AppProperties class just to be complete:
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "com.test")
@Data
public class AppProperties {

    private int port;
}


I got some support from a colleague.
The propagation works in the application, when you start it.
Just as a SpringBootTest, you need to annotate the test with
@AutoConfigureObservability
I got this hint:
https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide#testing
Hope it helps others as well.
